# jQuery ajax call does not launch callback when data type is 'script'

Tags: ajax, jquery, callback, jquery-callback, jquery-1.6

For example with jQuery 1.5.2 or smaller this code will log 'ololo' in FireBug console:

```
$.get(
'some_url', 
{ data: 'some_data' }, 
function() { 
   console.log('ololo') 
}, 
'script')
```

Same with .ajax (any type of request), .post

But with jQuery 1.6-1.6.1 the callback does nothing. However, the callback will be launched if data type is anything except 'script'. For example, 'json' or 'html.'

I have not been able to find something concerning this on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Can you not use $.getScript()?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "script" datatype makes jquery behave like [`getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) which

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then
>   execute it.

To me that means that no callback will be called, as the script will be executed.